# Facebook Debugger not finding my meta tags

Tags: facebook, metadata, facebook-opengraph

I'm having an issue with Facebook debugger. I'm trying to add OpenGraph data, but FaceBook is just not seeing it.
You can see it here:

http://www.heartmdinstitute.com/

I created a test page for testing purposes and FB does see data here:

http://www.heartmdinstitute.com/test_fb.php

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.heartmdinstitute.com%2F

Answer (score -2):

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="your app id" />
```

you have to put the above meta tag with your app id

Comment: Actually you don't. (the second link doesn't have FB App ID, and it works)

Comment: It is impossible to work without FB App ID. You can check the documentation of open graph api

Comment: @koushik: What you’re saying here is just not true. app_id is only needed if you want to f.e. be able to _moderate_ comments made using the comments plugin on your page, but there is no general need to embed an app id for the simple purpose of sharing with the correct meta data.

Comment: I've found that without the app_id your like/share button will not work as well. I now include both the app_id and the page id or whatever that one is called (property="fb:admins").